# How to write a sql statement that finds the clients with same fee schedules?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Lets say a house cleaning company has table fee_schedule, which lists the fees charged for each type of task.

```
create table fee_schedule (
  clientId int, 
  feeType int,
  feeAmount int,  /*dollars*/
  primary key (clientId, feeType)
);
```

Here are the fees:

```
Client 1 (Google)
    feeType 1 (Window Cleaning)  $10 (per each window)
    feeType 2 (Carpet Cleaning)  $20 (per room)
    feeType 3 (Emptying trashcans)  $30 (per trash can)
    feeType 4 (Dusting)  $40 (per room)

Client 2 (Facebook)
    feeType 1 (Window Cleaning)  $10 (per each window)
    feeType 2 (Carpet Cleaning)  $20 (per room)
    feeType 3 (Emptying trashcans)  $31 (per trash can)
    feeType 4 (Dusting)  $41 (per room)

Client 3 (Apple)
    feeType 1 (Window Cleaning)  $12 (per each window)
    feeType 2 (Carpet Cleaning)  $22 (per room)
    feeType 3 (Emptying trashcans)  $32 (per trash can)
    feeType 4 (Dusting)  $42 (per room)

Client 4 (Twitter)
    feeType 1 (Window Cleaning)  $10 (per each window)
    feeType 2 (Carpet Cleaning)  $20 (per room)
    feeType 3 (Emptying trashcans)  $30 (per trash can)
    feeType 4 (Dusting)  $40 (per room)
```

Here is sample data:

```
insert into fee_schedule values (1, 1, 10);
insert into fee_schedule values (1, 2, 20);
insert into fee_schedule values (1, 3, 30);
insert into fee_schedule values (1, 4, 40);

insert into fee_schedule values (2, 1, 10);
insert into fee_schedule values (2, 2, 20);
insert into fee_schedule values (2, 3, 31);
insert into fee_schedule values (2, 4, 41);

insert into fee_schedule values (3, 1, 12);
insert into fee_schedule values (3, 2, 22);
insert into fee_schedule values (3, 3, 32);
insert into fee_schedule values (3, 4, 42);

insert into fee_schedule values (4, 1, 10);
insert into fee_schedule values (4, 2, 20);
insert into fee_schedule values (4, 3, 30);
insert into fee_schedule values (4, 4, 40);
```

I wrote a query to get a list of which clients have the same exact fee schedule as client #1, Google.

```
select distinct f2.clientId
from fee_schedule f
join fee_schedule f2 on f.feeType=f2.feeType and f.feeAmount=f2.feeAmount
where f.clientId<f2.clientId
```

The query returns clients 2 and 4, but client 2 should not be returned as its fees are only partially the same.  How can I edit this query to only return results when ALL fees match?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of matches, using `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select f.clientId
from fee_schedule f left join
     fee_schedule fg
     on f.feeType = fg.feeType and f.feeAmount = fg.feeAmount and fg.clientid = 1
group by f.clientid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from fee_schedule f where f.clientid = 1) and
       count(fg.clientid) = count(*);
```

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can also do this using `group_concat()`:

```
select f.client_id
from fee_schedule f
group by f.client_id
having group_concat(fee_type, ':', fee_amount order by fee_type, fee_amount) =
       (select group_concat(fee_type, ':', fee_amount order by fee_type, fee_amount) as fees
        from fee_schedule
        where client_id = 1
       );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfe40d/7) is a SQL Fiddle with the two queries.